# In Elasticsearch, how do I combine multiple filters with OR without affecting the score?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

In Elasticsearch, I want to filter my results with two different clauses aggregated with OR e.g. return documents with PropertyA=true OR PropertyB=true.

I've been trying to do this using a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html). My base query is just a text search in `must`. If I put both clauses in the `filter` occurrence type, it aggregates them with an AND. If I put both clauses in the `should` occurrence type with `minimum_should_match` set to 1, then I get the right results. But then, documents matching both conditions get a higher score because "should" runs in a query context.

How do I filter to only documents matching either of two conditions, without increasing the score of documents matching both conditions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leverage the [`constant_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html), so everything runs in the filter context:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "PropertyA": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "PropertyB": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In case it's useful for anyone looking at this, I asked the same question on the Elasticsearch forums and got more context + the NEST syntax here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-combine-multiple-filters-with-or-without-affecting-the-score/284349/2